# MySQL "date_sub(now(), INTERVAL X" Error Code: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xEF\x80\xA6Top...' for column 's' at row 3

Tags: mysql, date

I have a problem here thats really puzzling me. I have a MySQL query, that works fine.. for the most part. In the query, Im looking at dates and date ranges from a table, and returning results that are X days old from today. It looks like this:

```
    WHERE tickets.date_created > date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Under most conditions, the query works fine. However, if I change the interval to a number between 80 to 97 my script fails to execute. The error I get is:

```
    Error Code: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xEF\x80\xA6Top...' for column 's' at row 3
```

Also, tryin 3 months, rather than 90 days doesnt work. There appear to be other numbers in the 100's that dont work too, however, if I set something like 10000 days, all results return ok.

Is this something in my database? Is it my query? Has anyone seen this with a date interval? What am I doing wrong?

Any thoughts anyone has :)

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is related to the date? What is in column `s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer!

There is a function built into our MySQL to strip out HTML and other characters from a returned result. Whilst its not performing any action on the date area (or shouldn't be) as its in my select statement:

```
   mycleanup (left(tickets_messages.message, 250))
```

It appears that if I change this to simply

```
   left(tickets_messages.message, 250)
```

My query then works! Very odd, but I guess Ill have to find another way to work around stripping HTML and the like.